# Figma's dimension pixel for pixel in CSS

Tags: css, responsive-design, frontend, responsive, figma

When converting Figma design to HTML and CSS, do you copy the Figma's dimension pixel for pixel in CSS...

Anytime I copy the dimension pixel for pixel, it's either too small or too big but not far from what it's meant to look like.
Any tips on how to go about this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pixel dimensions in Figma and pixel dimensions in CSS should be the same.

Probably when designing, you're viewing the design only in Figma editor. Due to zoom in/out of the design file, you're not seeing how it will look in an actual device.

For example, you put font-size: 36px for a  and your design is zoomed out  50%. You will notice 36px is looking very small in the design. But when you add that into CSS and run it in the browser it looks good.

I would suggest always preview your design on a real device. Run the prototype in a browser for the desktop apps. And for previewing mobile apps use Figma mobile. I believe you'll figure out your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not talking about the design in Figma.
I'm talking about the design implementation when writing the HTML and CSS for web development.
When I copy the CSS dimensions from Figma to my css file, it doesn't translate accurately to what's in the figma design